# Unable to run Scala application in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a simple Scala snippet,

```
package example

class HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

in the IntelliJ IDE with Scala installed. However, the "Run" button appears to be grayed out, and I also don't see it in the context menu (not shown in the screen grab below).

[image]

In accordance with the answer of [Unable to run Java code with Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923909/unable-to-run-java-code-with-intellij-idea), the code is in the `src` folder which is marked blue. (I've also tried marking it as a 'tests' folder but to no avail). What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`HelloWorld` should be `object`, not `class`:

```
package example

object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

For more info about singleton objects, you can see [this chapter](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html#4.3) of "Programming in Scala" book and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala).